# How to get post count of a custom query in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, implode, array-map

When I try to get the post count of a custom query in wordpress I get the following error as output.

```
Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 1918

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php on line 1918
0
```

So below is my function:

```
   if( !function_exists('my_likes') ){
    function my_likes() {
      global $current_user;
      $current_user = get_current_user_id();
       // The Query
      $args = array(
        'meta_key' =>'likes_count',
        'orderby' => 'date',
        'post__in' => $current_user
       );
       $obj_name = new WP_Query($args);
       $num = $obj_name->post_count;
       print $num;
       }
     add_action('my_likes', 'my_likes');
    }
```

Comment: I think you will want to use `$obj_name->found_posts` instead. To get the total number of posts WP_Query returns use "found_posts".

Comment: I use the same query in a custom page template where I list current user likes using meta_key but here as a function it doesn't get the count

Comment: Same echo with `$obj_name->found_posts;` I think there ius a problem with the `$current_user` global

Comment: Have you added `echo $obj_name->found_posts;`

Answer (score 0):

```
count($obj_name->posts)
```

This is an inefficient way to count user posts as it gets all the post object. Perhaps just use a raw SQL query

Comment: maybe this is the correct answer for the title but as I see the errors are coming from `$current_user` the mistake must be there I'm using meta_key with the custom field for positive like added by the user, so its working in a page template but I'm getting the following errors that you see in my question.

Answer (score 0):

The line `'post__in' => $current_user` is incorrect the post__in should be an array so if you want to use it like this you would need to do `'post__in' => array($current_user)`

Also from the context i am not sure is you want to use this line at all, if you want to count posts posted by user identified by $current_user then instead of `'post__in' => $current_user` you should use `'author' => $current_user`

BTW. the line `global $current_user;` is not needed there at all and overtwites the global $current_user value.

The complete code should look like this i think

```
function my_likes() {
  $current_user = get_current_user_id();
   // The Query
  $args = array(
    'meta_key' =>'likes_count',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'post__in' => array($current_user),
    // or 'author' => $current_user
   );
   $obj_name = new WP_Query($args);
   $num = $obj_name->post_count;
   print $num;
 }
```

Comment: Yes but with the same query in a custom page template I list the liked posts of a current user using theme like dislike system which one works using custom field called "likes_count" I'm also using in query as meta_key and its working fine when I use in the custom page template the the trick does the job but here with the function I'm not able to get the count do you recommend any different way or function?

Comment: `'post__in' => array($current_user),` is giving the number 0 page in the page template using the found posts I get the correct number and posts

Comment: yes thats not working in the page template too sorry, however I don't know what to do to. So when I click on like button it works via ajax and adds a custom field called 'likes_count' so what I want is listing all posts that I liked or to get the number of liked posts for the current user using a custom query.